# How to position a Recycler View like Google Play Store or Google Music in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I position a Recycler View like this.

It initially begins on the right edge of the view showing only just a few elements. And once you begin scrolling, all other elements starts showing.

[image]

---

[image]

The default Recycler View would position all elements from the leftmost part of the view.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: add a first item transparent?

Comment: yep, add a transparent placeholder item as the 0th element. Redefine `getItemViewType()` in your adapter.

Comment: what rupps suggest is a nice trick, that would indeed work. Set the visibility of a like sized item to be "View.INVISIBLE" so it isn't visible, but still occupies space. Then onscroll set the visibility to "View.GONE" so it's still invisible but the space is filled in by the rest of the elements

Comment: Thanks rupps, EpicPandaForce and Lucas Crawford. I followed rupps trick..using the getItemViewType to create/inflate a transparent ViewHolder on the 0th item..

Answer (score 2):

I read the other comments and felt like adding this answer. Adding a new type is overkill for achieving your goal. There's a much simpler way (Which I suppose is used in Google Play Music app).

Add horizontal padding to your RecyclerView and prevent clipping.

Here is what it would look like in xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />
```

The key here is `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a `ViewPager` for the horizontal scrollable list of items.

With a `ViewPager` you can use the following snippet to indent the items:

```
ViewPager.setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```